# index of current clicked element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I would like to know, how it is possible to log the index of a current clicked element of an array.

The array:

```
var cubesmixed = []; 
var cubes;
for(var i = 0; i < 149; i++) {
    cubes = paper.rect(Math.floor(Math.random()*2000), Math.floor(Math.random()*2000), 0, 0);
    cubesmixed.push(cubes);
}
```

and the `click` function:

```
$(this).click(function() 
{ 
   console.log(index of current clicked element in cubesmixed); 
});
```

I'm calling all inside a `ready()` function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the context (i.e. the surrounding code) of those snippets? I'm not sure where you're calling the `$(this).click(...);` part, and its location makes a *huge* difference.

Comment: I'm calling this after the array was created.

Comment: Calling it *how*? Is it just that one line on its own? If so, `this` is the entire window and that's totally wrong. Inside a loop over the array? If so, post that loop. What does the `paper.rect` function do? Does it just create a rectangle that isn't anywhere, or does it add actual elements to the document?

Comment: http://jobs.super-sized.de/web_try/ I've uploaded it to show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm not sure i understood what you need (array in this context is a javascript object, not a DOM element, so i can't understand how can someone click it).

anyway, check out jQuery `.index()` method: http://api.jquery.com/index/

usage:

```
console.log($(this).index())
```

hope it helps

**UPDATE:**

view comments for full solution

Comment: I assume that each element of the array is a DOM node that can be clicked, and they want to know its position in the array when one of them is clicked on. Assuming array order is the same as their order in the DOM, the `.index()` function might work.

Comment: what type of element is created in `paper.rect()` ? <div> ?

Comment: make sure all the child elements that are created are placed into one common container like `<div class="container"> [child items] </div>`

Comment: `paper.rect()` is a raphael.js object.

Comment: yes but it seems to create dom elements as well, can you check it via chrome's "inspect element" or something ?

Comment: @GalV http://jobs.super-sized.de/web_try/ I've uploaded it for better understanding!!

Comment: i tried this script and it worked: $(function(){$('rect').click(function(){alert($(this).index())})});

i clicked a rect AFTER i hovered "mario" / "link" and it alerted the index of the rect

Answer (score 0):

(Replace `#items` with your selector...)

```
$('#items').each(function(index,element){

   $(element).click(function(){
      console.log(index);
   });

})
```

This will be more efficient than `.index()` **if** jQuery does no caching on the call.

```
.index() -> O(n) * invocationCount
```

as opposed to the above method which is just `O(n)` once for initial setup

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your code. Each cube you're creating already has an id. I just added this piece of code to yours and it worked.

```
cubesmixed.forEach(function(cube){
    cube.click(function(){
        console.log("Cube clicked: " + cube.id); 
    });
});
```

This is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fraximus/jYGR9/